# Automatically create calendar event from gmail

Tags: google-schemas

I am using below code to schedule the calendar event but it is not working. I am able to get an email but calender event is not scheduled automatically.

mail_tamplate.html

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/ConfirmAction",
  "name": "Rahul Kumar",
  "description": "Desc of event",
  "startDate": "2017-01-05T20:00",
  "endDate": "2017-01-05T21:00",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "South Ex",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "178-C",
      "addressLocality": "Meerut",
      "addressRegion": "Uttar Pradesh",
      "postalCode": "250001",
      "addressCountry": "India"
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
function testSchemas() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'Test Email markup - ' + new Date(),
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible.

> Actions enable users to interact with your product or service right inside Gmail and Inbox.
>
> For instance, when a user receives an invitation to an event, she may be presented the option to RSVP interactively to the event from right inside the invitation. When she receives a notification that a magazine subscription is about to expire, she may be presented the option to renew it right from the notification.
>
> Actions can be declared in two ways: as In-App Actions or as Go-To Actions. Multiple types of actions are currently supported.
>
> #### RSVP Action
>
> - A [RsvpAction](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rsvp-action) can be used for responding to an event invitation from inside the inbox. The inbox renders this action by showing the details of the event and a combination of Yes/No/Maybe responses defined by the sender.

[image]

Interaction with the user is needed before the event is added.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to use this option. I want to automatically add an event in the google calendar who receives the email. I have tried various jsonld by using the below URL but it is not working.    https://hallanalysis.com/json-ld-generator/

Comment: I was also chasing this goal, but in hindsight I think it's just not possible - the potential for spam to fill someone's calendar with events they haven't actually requested would be a chaotic mess, even with the SPF and registration hoops, etc.

Better to use RsvpAction as Mr Rebot suggests, so there's only the minimal acceptance step for the user. Beyond that, you might need to use the Google Calendar API directly.